# Ubuntu 16.04: No sidebar/playlist in Totem

Tags: 16.04, totem

I can't get the playlist to show in Totem. The Help page says "To show or hide the playlist, choose *View* ▸ *Sidebar* or click on the *Sidebar* button, and choose *Playlist* on the top of the sidebar." But when I choose *View*, there is no *Sidebar* option, nor is there any *Sidebar* button.

Comment: I have the same issue. The *View* menu is missing in the *Sidebar* option. Might be a bug.

Comment: This issue is now reported as [Bug #1600606](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+bug/1600606). Please hop on to Launchpad to indicate this bug also affects you. When the bug is accept this question should be closed.

Comment: Don't you all get it?? there is no sidebar anymore, only the overview which also serves as a playlst of sorts. That bug report will go nowhere & should be marked as invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using [Parole](http://docs.xfce.org/apps/parole/start) instead. It's very much like old Totem interface and there is the sidebar functionality.